# How to trigger input tag validation when initialize?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input

I'm making a form of checkbox input list.
But the checkbox has some limit.  It's Max and min validation.

For example, for 10 checkbox, I should check at least 2 and 5 maximum.

So I decided to use ngMin and ngMax with another input Tag.

```
<label ng-repeat="a in a.list">
     <input type="checkbox"
           data-checklist-model="value"
           data-checklist-value="attributeValue">{{a.text}}<span/>
</label>

<input type="number"
       ng-model="value.length"
        min="2"
        max="5"
        min-err-type="EE"
        max-err-type="RR"/>
```

But after loaded, I clicked 6 checkboxes. But min-err-type and max-err-type doesn't worked.

However when I changed the input number manually, 
From that moment all validation worked well.

I could not find how to work validation properly right after loaded.

Comment: why closing tag for ```<input>``` is ```<span/>```?

Comment: @VasylButov your question is right but just to be clear `<input>` doesn't have a closing tag

Comment: `checklist-model`, `checklist-value` are not AngularJS directives. Neither is `min-err-type` and `max-err-type`. Please include the code for those validators.